# Cannot post to express api from next.js api route ( nextauth )

Tags: express, next.js, next-auth

I have an express server running on port 8080 and my nextjs app running on port 3000. I'm using nextauth to log in using credentials ( sending username and password to express api on port 8080 to validate ). For some reason, I always seem to get a 404 error on posting to

```
localhost:8080/api/public/signin
```

, which is my express signin endpoint.

pages/api/auth/[...nextauth].js has this content

```
export default NextAuth({
...
providers: [
  Providers.Credentials({
    name: "Email/Password",
    credentials: {
      email: { label: "Email", type: "text" },
      password: { label: "Password", type: "password" },
    },
    async authorize(credentials) {
      let user = await axios
        .post("localhost:8080/api/public/signin", {
          ...credentials,
        })
        .then((res) => res.data)
        .catch((e) => console.log("login failed", e));

    
      if (user && user.name && user.user_type) {
        return user;
      } else {
        throw new Error("Login failed. Please check email and password");
      }
    },
  })
]}
```

The endpoint works fine when hit from either postman, or from a page (from the browser).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding the protocol (`http://`) ?

I'm not sure axios can take semi absolute URLs like that. Since its not a relative URL (i.e. only `/api/public/signin`), but its not a full absolute URL either.

Comment: Thanks for responding!. Yeah, I tried that. It doesn't look like an issue with absolute/relative URLs. For some reason, when both the express server and the nextJS server are running on localhost, they don't seem to be able to connect to each other. For now, I've got my setup running by running containers for the next app and the express app on the same docker custom bridge network... but it's a pain to build and run containers like this. I just cannot understand what the issue is here.

Comment: Ah they're running in containers? Yeah then you definitely need at least a docker bridge network between the two or you can allow both containers to use the host's network (`--network host`)

https://docs.docker.com/network/host/

Comment: oh no, I'm running them on containers because I couldn't get it to work otherwise, ie when both were independently running on ports 3000 and 8080 respectively. I was at least able to get them to communicate when using containers, so I did it to move on. But the original issue is still there.

Comment: And also, I notice that this is not happening only with the next auth API route, but all API routes/server-side data fetching as well.. basically whenever next js makes API requests from the server-side to express app, I get 404... so I guess this is probably something stupid I'm doing or something that I missed to set up.

Comment: @Sachin did you manage to fix the issue without using containers? I just came across this issue and I'm looking for a solution. I know I can split my app in two separate ports but I think next "is blocking" my request to express route.